# Restart GPS after device reboot on ios

Tags: ios, gps, reboot

I am new to ios and writing an application which uses GPS. This application works even in background. The problem I am facing here is, after device(ios) reboot my application which is in background doesn't receive any GPS updates. (I need to relaunch the app on device for it to receive gps updates)

Can any one suggest me how to overcome this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` when  app goes to background.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

}
```

Now when you device rebooted and whenever there is any location updates available ( as per the crieterion of `SignificantLocationChanges`) your app automatically invoke from background and app runs is background.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` of `CLLocationManager` class. As per the apple documentation, even if system kills your application, it will invoke your application again when your device moves significantly.